# Launch new app from app in new tab Angular-Node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have an Angular 1.x - Node application. I need to launch another alike application from the first one, in a new tab, using Google Chrome.
The process flow is the following:
- user starts from a page listing a number of applications available.
- user clicks on a Run button, defined as here (is inside a table row):

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.onSubmit({'operation': 'run', 'slug': application.slug, 'port': application.port});">Run</button></td>
```

- the onSubmit click handler, from the view's Angular controller, sends the JSON data, via an http POST request, to the appropriate Node controller.
- the Node controller starts the server's application as following:

```
console.log("Application run request on the server side, port: " + req.body.port + " slug: " + req.body.slug);
            var fork = require('child_process').fork;
            var child = fork('../../' + req.body.slug);
            res.status(200).json({ "port": req.body.port });
```

- the .success method of the http POST request in the Angular controller picks up the application-to-open-in-new-tab port

```
return $http.post('/api/applications', data)
                    .success(function (result) {
                        console.log("port is " + result.port);
                        // What should I do here (and elsewhere)?
                    })
                    // catch the error message
                    .error(function (error) {
                        vm.error = error;
                    });
```

and ... here I need your help!
All the process flow works fine up to this point, the new application instance is launched in Node (the above console message is displayed, and, if I open manually a new tab and make http://localhost:port_nb, I'm getting what I need to be display-triggered automatically from the first application).
My question is: where in the Angular space (view-controller) and how should I implement something close to

```
$window.open('http://localhost:port_nb', '_blank');
```

knowing that this would work on a direct button click, which is not my case.
A formal answer would be perhaps "create a click event", but that doesn't come up into my mind how.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implemenet `onSubmit` method in Angular's controller as follows

```
vm.onSumbit = function(data) {
    return $http.post('/api/applications', data)
                .success(function (result) {
                    console.log("port is " + result.port);
                    $window.open('http://localhost:' + result.port, '_blank');
                })
                // catch the error message
                .error(function (error) {
                    vm.error = error;
                });

}
```

Also make sure to reference the controller `Controller as vm`.

#### Side note:

It is best to store `$http` requests in a factory or a service.

Comment: Thanks Deividas, I've been done that from the beginning without paying attention at the pop-up blocker of Chrome. With your response I watched attentively the small icon upper right, allowed the pop-ups and it's fine now.